# Nuget Server backwards compatibility

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

We are in the process of setting up new infrastructure for our dev team, one of the things that we are doing is setting up an internal nuget server.

We have followed the guide here https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds and everything is working. However some of our dev team still rely on Visual studio 2012 which does not seem to work with this server, I assume that this is because the API has moved on and the client built into 2012 cannot connect to the server.

My question is what is the best way to deal with this, we have a mix of VS2012 and 2015 in use, It occurs to me that we could set up another server using an older version of the nuget server and point it at the same packages directory, however I am not convinced that this is the correct course of action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to support NuGet v2 clients, such as Visual Studio 2012 then you need to provide a NuGet v2 server. NuGet v2 clients cannot use a NuGet v3 server if it only provides the index.json endpoint.

Options are:

1. Use an older version of NuGet.Server that supports NuGet v2.
2. Use a file share instead of a server.
3. Use some other server instead that provides a NuGet v2 server, such as MyGet, or one that you can host locally such as Team City.
4. Update to Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Pretty much what we already thought. It needs to be internal, so I think the option that we go with will be to set up a second nuget server pointed at the same packages directory.

While upgrading to 2015 would be ideal unfortunately its not an option. Thanks.